# IOS Sinch voip call - Failed to decode message transport

Tags: ios, sinch

My incoming calls are constantly getting disconnected while it's ringing in (at least 3 times out 10 times)

The below is the log message when this happens.

(I'm using SinchRTC 3.4.1)

**(SINLogSeverityTrace log)**

> REQUEST 3: Request PUT
>   https://sandbox.sinch.com/V1/Session{"ApplicationKey”:”My
>   ApplicationKey”,”CallStatistics":{"AudioLevelsDescription":["Timestamp","AudioInputLevel","AudioOutputLevel"],"AudioLevelsSamples":[],"Codecs":[],"RTCPDescription":["Timestamp","PacketsSent","PacketsReceived","PacketsLost","RTTMs","JitterReceivedMs"],"RTCPSamples":[],"RTCPTimestampBase":"1425452945396","RTCPTimestampNormalization":true,"ReportVersion":"2"},"CallTime":"/Date(1425452945396)/","ConnectionInfo":{"Host":"","Port":0,"Protocol":"","Type":""},"DeviceInformation":{"ModelId":"iPhone5,2","ModelName":"","OSName":"iOS","OSVersion":"8.3","PerformanceCharacteristics":"highend","SDKPlatform":"iOS","SDKPlatformVersion":"3.4.1"},"Domain":"","Duration":"0","FromId”:”MyFromId”,”Headers":{"ph":"{\"SIN\":\"Test
>   SIN call
>   header\"}\n"},"InstanceId":"98f61bf2-4439-41a5-ac78-a286f3d3eed4","MXPEventLog":{"Events":[["OUT","SENDING","2DE4D14E-5470-41C5-9309-BF942B948405","1425452945479","0","ACK","","{\"channel\":\"0b1ca3d2-94e6-4e65-9834-6d260abb310dS\"}"],["OUT","SENDING","2DE4D14E-5470-41C5-9309-BF942B948405","1425452945494","0","PEEREVENT","","{\"channel\":\"0b1ca3d2-94e6-4e65-9834-6d260abb310dS\"}"],["OUT","SENDING","2DE4D14E-5470-41C5-9309-BF942B948405","1425452945616","0","PEEREVENT","","{\"channel\":\"0b1ca3d2-94e6-4e65-9834-6d260abb310dS\"}"],["ERROR","","2DE4D14E-5470-41C5-9309-BF942B948405","1425452945662","{\"reason\":\"Failed
>   to decode message
>   transport\"}"],["ERROR","","2DE4D14E-5470-41C5-9309-BF942B948405","1425452945662","{\"reason\":\"Failed
>   to decode message
>   transport\"}"],["OUT","SENDING","2DE4D14E-5470-41C5-9309-BF942B948405","1425452945662","0","ERROR","{\"error\":\"Failed
>   to decode message
>   transport\"}","{\"channel\":\"0b1ca3d2-94e6-4e65-9834-6d260abb310dS\"}"]],"Version":"2"},"Outbound":false,"Result":"4","SessionId":"2DE4D14E-5470-41C5-9309-BF942B948405","SetupDuration":"0","Signature":"3+cqz4D6N9dpwS8w9mxAz7gW3oQ=","ToId”:”My
>   ToId”,”UserId”:”MyUserId”}

**(SINLogSeverityCritical log)**

> Failed to decode message transport
>
> Failed to decode message transport

I wonder what situation causes this kind of problem.

Anyone with a similar problem?

Comment: I have notified our sdk team, it will take a few hours before I can get a response. But we are on it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you been using an older version of the Sinch SDK (iOS or Android) during testing? This problem might result from creating many instances for the same user id on multiple SDK versions. One way to test this hypothesis would be to start your Sinch client with a new unused user id using the latest SDK for iOS and Android (https://www.sinch.com/downloads/) - you should not be getting this error in that case. Meanwhile we will continue investigating on our side why those rare cases (as described above) are failing to connect.